# GRUB "no such partition error"

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have a dual booted Windows/Linux computer.

Today when I turn it on, it says:

```
error: no such partition.
Grubrescue >
```

What do I do?

Comment: Do you have 2 hard drives?

Answer (score 0):

I recently have the same thing happen to me after an update. The quick and easy thing I did was use boot-repair. It'll fix most grub issues. [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)